# Is it a mistake in Apostol's Calculus?

Tags: calculus

Can you please check. I think it is a mistake in the answers of *Apostol's Calculus vol.1*.

> (*page 268*)
>   Find a function $f$, continuous for all $x$ (and not everywhere zero),
>   such that
>
> $$f^2(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \frac{\sin(t)}{2 + \cos(t)}dt$$

My answer is
$$\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{3}{2 + \cos(x)}\right)$$

while in the answers
$$\log\left(\frac{3}{2 + \cos(x)}\right)$$

I differentiate both sides and find the derivative of $f$, and then integrate back and choose $C$ so that $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating gives $\displaystyle 2 f(x) f'(x) = f(x) \frac{\sin(x)}{2 + \cos(x)}$. Cancellation and integration gives $2 f(x) = -\ln|2 + \cos(x)| +C$. Your observation of the condition that $f(0) = 0$ gives $C = \ln(3)$. Putting this together we have $2 f(x) = \ln\left|\frac{3}{2 + \cos(x)}\right|$, so your answer seems to be a correct one.